# Is indexing the answer MySQL online database thousands of records

Tags: mysql, indexing, performance

I'm soon to have an application that has uses online database (MySQL). I could have many thousands of records in a particular table in my database. Am I going to see a performance hit? What about if I turn on indexing. Is indexing is all handled transparent (it's all handled for me)? Or should good practice be to try and catergorize the data into other tables (such as alphabetically). Isn't this what indexing basically does?

Any other advice... I'm quite new to online connectivity. I mostly develop for standalone computer.

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

you should always index if appropriate but there's not enough information provided to know what should be indexed. Many thousands for any db is not a *lot*,

Comment: @Tom - Just to elaborate a bit more, Indexes need to be chosen correctly keeping in mind how your data is queried. I am not even sure what you mean by "turning on indexing". Its not exactly a switch on / switch off feature. More info here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are useful to speed up queries that identfy a tiny subset of all records. Indexes are sorted (well not all types of indexes), which means they may also speed up certain queries where you need the rows in the same order as the columns in the index.

Indexes will not help you if you are selecting larger subsets of the data in your table, other than the special case where the index includes all columns referenced by your query.

Comment: when you say "Indexes will not help you if you are selecting larger subsets of the data in your table" do you mean when you just say I want records x to n? I have created an index on the my table on the name field as I query this. Does the index basically do something along the lines of when I pass a query on the name field, instead of doing a linear search, it knows that my paramters passed, say name=thomas, that thomas is near the middle of the alphabet so it starts the linear search after say the letter m?